# Dynamically show or hide fields depending on radio button

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 radio buttons based on which I want to show or hide 2 different option fields.

```
<p id="proposition">
      <label for='propositionC'>choice : </label>
      <input type="radio" name="rep" value="yes" id="yes" required/>Yes
      <input type="radio" name="rep" value="no" id="no" />NO
</p>
```

And this is how I try to change it :

```
if (reason==6)
        {
            $("#proposition").slideDown('fast');
            var choice =  $('input[name=rep]:checked','#proposition').val();
            if(choice =="yes")
            {
                $("#pCr").hide();
                $("#pBq").slideDown('fast');
            }
          else if(choice =="no")
           {
                $("#pBq").hide();
                $("#pCr").slideDown('fast'); 
           }
        }
```

this code is not stable since it only works the first time but when I change yes to no for example it's blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you only check the value once, when the page loads.

To fix this you need to add a `change` event handler to both radio buttons and place the respective logic within that:

```js
var reason = 6;
if (reason == 6) {
  $("#proposition").slideDown('fast');
}

// somewhere else in your logic..
$('input[name=rep]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
    $("#pCr").hide();
    $("#pBq").slideDown('fast');
  } else {
    $("#pBq").hide();
    $("#pCr").slideDown('fast');
  }
});
```

```css
#proposition, #pCr, #pBq { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="proposition">
  <label for='propositionC'>choice : </label>
  <input type="radio" name="rep" value="yes" id="yes" required/>Yes
  <input type="radio" name="rep" value="no" id="no" />NO
</p>

<div id="pCr">pCr</div>
<div id="pBq">pBq</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Have you console logged what `$('input[name=rep]:checked','#proposition').val()` returns? I'm guessing it's not what you're expecting since you're giving it two selectors. Try just `$('input[name=rep]:checked').val()`

Scratch that. After a quick fiddle I realized you're code checks out. Do you have a bind somewhere else in you code to check your inputs when they're clicked and not just on first load?

```
$("#proposition")
  .slideDown('fast')
  .find('input[name=rep]')
    .on('click', function() {
      var choice =  this.value;

      if (reason === 6) {
        if(choice =="yes") {
          $("#pCr").hide();
          $("#pBq").slideDown('fast');
        } else if(choice =="no") {
          $("#pBq").hide();
          $("#pCr").slideDown('fast'); 
         }
       }
    });
```